# Problem using the QUERY function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a list of companies a list of their different social media platforms going across in columns. There are many duplicates on this list. Using the "QUERY" function combined with COUNTA I can tabulate how many accounts each company has of the various types. The QUERY part of the function looks like this:

```
=query(A1:D7, "select A where (A='" & A11 & "' and B='Facebook')")
```

Now, instead of having to have to change the formula for each row, I'd like it to replace the "11" with the ROW() function... but it doesn't seem to work to just go

```
=query(A1:D7, "select A where (A='" & A & ROW() & "' and B='Facebook')")
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:
You A&ROW() is not going to work as a cell reference. You should use INDIRECT("A"&ROW()) instead.

Normally when copy down formula, cell references change too. So you don't need to use ROW().
Only when you use absolute reference like $A$11 it does not change during dragging or copying formula.

Check INDIRECT reference: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en

Comment: Thanks! When I tried the INDIRECT function but couldn't get it to work because I was was using a comma rather than an "&" for some reason.  Good point about relative vs absolute cell references. Thanks!